# In testing in java how to check if a method of an interface is called or not?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, jmockit

I want to test this class which calls a method of interface using anonymous class.

```
public class ClassToTest 
{
    public void methodToTest()
    {
        InterefaceToMock interefaceToMockReference = new InterefaceToMock() {

            @Override
            public int methodToMock()
            {
                return 0;
            }
        };
        interefaceToMockReference.methodToMock();
    }
}
```

This is the interface

```
public interface InterefaceToMock 
{
    public int methodToMock();
}
```

I am using this approch to check it methodToMock is called or not

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

import mockit.FullVerificationsInOrder;
import mockit.Mocked;
import mockit.NonStrictExpectations;
public class TestAClass 
{
    @Mocked InterefaceToMock interefaceToMockReferenceMocked;
    @Test
    public void test1()
    {
        new NonStrictExpectations()
        {
            {
                interefaceToMockReferenceMocked.methodToMock();times=1;
            }
        };
        (new ClassToTest()).methodToTest();
        new FullVerificationsInOrder(interefaceToMockReferenceMocked)
        {
        };
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

But test case fails.
Can anyone help.

Comment: I don't understand what's going on here. How does `InterefaceToMock.methodToMock()` get called by `ClassToTest.methodToTest()` if a reference to the instance is never passed in?

Comment: How does it fail?  AssertTrue(true) can never fail.  Messy, confusing code.  Bad naming.

Comment: @BoristheSpider It is called using anonymous class object.

Comment: @duffymo It is failing in verification.

Comment: Either the expectation recording block or the expectation verification block should be removed here, since you only need one in this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original test was almost correct. It declared the mock field as simply being `@Mocked`, which merely gives you a single mocked instance implementing the interface, and this is not the one used by the code under test. The JMockit API has another mocking annotation, however, which extends mocking to all implementation classes from a given base type, and by default affects all instances of said classes. So, the test should be changed as follows:

```
public class TestAClass 
{
    @Capturing InterfaceToMock anyImplementingInstance;

    @Test
    public void test1()
    {
        new ClassToTest().methodToTest();

        new Verifications() {{
            anyImplementingInstance.methodToMock();
        }};
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is working. I have used this approch as you suggested in comment that I should use expectaion verification block or expectation recording block. `code` import org.junit.Test;
import mockit.Capturing;
import mockit.NonStrictExpectations;
public class TestAClass 
{
    @Capturing InterfaceToMock anyImplementingInstance;

    @Test
    public void test1()
    {
     
     new NonStrictExpectations()
  {
   {
    anyImplementingInstance.methodToMock();times=1;
   }
  };
     
        new ClassToTest().methodToTest();
        
    }
}`code`

Comment: This approch is also working.`code` new NonStrictExpectations()
  {
      @Capturing InterfaceToMock anyImplementingInstance;
   {
    anyImplementingInstance.methodToMock();times=1;
   }
  };`code` May I use this approch. Because I don't want InterfaceToMock to be mocked in other test methods.

Comment: No, local mock fields are no longer supported. You should use mock *parameters* for mocking that is restricted to a single test.

Comment: Maven does not support passing parameters in test cases.

Comment: No, but JMockit does; try it (just to be clear, I meant *test method* parameters).

Comment: It works. But when we use maven install maven shows error that there should be no parameters in test methods.

Comment: In that case you should move the `jmockit` dependency *before* `junit` in the pom.xml file; or annotate each test class with `@RunWith(JMockit.class)`, so that classpath ordering doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

In the general case, if you have an `class` and you want to check whether a method on a `Mock` of that `class` is called, you use `Mockito.verify`.

For example:

```
public class AppTest {
    @Test
    public void testMe() {
        final ITest iTest = Mockito.mock(ITest.class);
        final CUT cut = new CUT(iTest);
        cut.doStuff();
        Mockito.verify(iTest).someStuff();
    }

    interface ITest {
        void someStuff();
    }

    class CUT {
        private final ITest iTest;

        CUT(ITest iTest) {
            this.iTest = iTest;
        }

        public void doStuff() {
            iTest.someStuff();
        }
    }
}
```

Here, the test is whether `ITest.someStuff()` is called from `CUT.doStuff()`.

Your example is undecipherable...

Comment: Thanks for your support. As you can see I can't pass mocked instance to the class I am testing. Like this  "final CUT cut = new CUT(iTest);" Please provide answer according to given example. I have to use JMockit. I can not use any other mocking frame work. This is a restriction. If you can't understand anything in example please do ask what is not clear.